# hbase client in sandboxed GAE environment

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to get google bigtable java client to work in GAE, which is a hbase client. I found an example, 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae
but it's only for managed vm in GAE tho.

When I tried to deploy test code to sandboxed GAE, I got this error msg:

> ```
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please
> ```
>
> see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.

see full stacktrace here: http://pastebin.com/ke5QMDGY

I'm curious if anyone has experience with the client in sandboxed GAE can give a few pointers.
Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Bigtable currently is NOT supported from the sandboxed GAE environment for JAVA.

Comment: so it is supported in sandboxed GAE? I'm following that tutorial example, But I'm getting this error:

      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.<clinit>(ManagementFactory.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.<clinit>(ReflectionUtils.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:45)

Comment: Are you using ConnectionFactory?  If so, can you use BigtableConnection directly?  Perhaps we should change the example code to do that as well.

Comment: gRPC doesn't work inside GAE for either Java / Python at this time.  My understanding is that Go is very close, but I haven't seen a definitive success announcement.

Comment: The problem at hand specifically relates to ConnectionFactory.  I guess there will be other problems with gRPC as well.

Comment: @Solomon Duskis Do you mean that using BigtableConfiguration.connect() instead of ConnectionFactory.createConnection() should do the trick?

Comment: gRPC is not currently supported on GAE Standard for Java and Python.  A solution is being worked on and we expect to have some news in Q1.  Go works now.  Please consider using [GAE Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java).